# what's the difference between Test.QuickCheck and Test.Tasty.QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, quickcheck

I am new to Quickcheck, and in my program,
    import Test.QuickCheck works, but
    import Test.Tasty.QuickCheck will report "Could not find module ‘Test.Tasty’"

Comment: This is a different package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-quickcheck

Comment: Tasty is an "umbrella" framework that unifies a few different approaches to testing.  Quickcheck is one such approach.  `Test.Tasty.QuickCheck` is the module that ties tasty and quickcheck together.

Comment: You also have `import Test.Tasty` somewhere, do you?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/), you need to build that package:

```sh
stack build tasty
stack build tasty-quickcheck
```

After that, `stack ghc ...` and `stack ghci` will be able to find the module `Test.Tasty.QuickCheck`.